# Drawing from one surface to another surface

Tags: python, cairo

```
import cairo
import math

w = 2000
h = 2000

surface = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, w, h)
ctx = cairo.Context(surface)
ctx.scale(w, h)

surface_path = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, w, h)
ctx_path = cairo.Context(surface_path)
ctx_path.scale(w, h)

surface_circle = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, w, h)
ctx_circle = cairo.Context(surface_circle)
ctx_circle.scale(w, h)

""" Lots of function calls that draw paths to surface_path and circles to surface_circle """

ctx.set_source_surface(surface_path, 0, 0)
ctx.paint()
ctx.set_source_surface(surface_circle, 0, 0)
ctx.paint()

surface_path.write_to_png("example.png")
surface_circle.write_to_png("example2.png")
surface.write_to_png("result.png")
```

[Imgur link to saved images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGRr7.jpg)

I am attempting to compile two surfaces (one with lines, one with circles) onto one separate surface, then save that to a file.

Despite following what the documentation suggests should work, the final image ends up blank.  I also tried calling `flush()` on `surface_path` and `surface_circle`, but that seemed to do nothing.

How could I combine the image info in `surface_circle` (example2.png) on top of `surface_path` (example.png), then output it to a file?

Comment: I'm not an expert in cairo, but I believe you need a "mask". For example, you select a source and draw a line. Along the path of the line, the source is copied to the destination. If you draw nothing, nothing is transfered. I would suggest you draw a big rectangle the size of the image. See http://cairographics.org/tutorial/#L1drawing

Comment: `ctx.set_source_surface(surface_path, 0, 0)
ctx.rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1)
ctx.fill()
ctx.set_source_surface(surface_circle, 0, 0)
ctx.stroke()
ctx.rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1)
ctx.fill()
ctx.stroke()`
 I tried that code, but it still doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling ctx.identity_matrix() before your last few paint() calls.

As is right-now, thanks to your call to ctx.scale(w, h), you only get the top-left pixels of those other surfaces scaled up to fill all of the target surface.

Comment: That seemed to have worked. I don't fully understand what scale() nor identity_matrix() does, though :( Could you briefly explain/link me to a resource that explains?

Comment: Well, scale applies a scaling to all the following operations. When you do scale(a, b), all coordinates you use later will be multiplied by a or b respectively. Put differently, it pretends that the surface you are painting to only has size 1/a, 1/b. In your code, it makes scales the surface so that all coordinates are between 0 and 1 instead of 0 and w or h. All that identity_matrix() does is to reset all scaling, translations etc and returns to no transformation at all. For some docs, see http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Transformations.html